# Unity 2D Top-Down Player flickers over the mouse pointer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making Top-Down shooter in Unity. I made PlayerMovement with "follow the mouse" logic. Now I would like to set that player sprite is not going over the mouse pointer with this:

```
if (Vector2.Distance(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), transform.position) <= 0.1f)
    {
        return;
    }
```

I really don't understand why this is not working. I tried setting the value higher than 0.1f but there is no difference.
[Here's the gif that shows exactly what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Ofe.jpg)

What other technique could I use to solve this problem?

Comment: It really could be possible that the distance difference between the mouse position translated, and the object is greater than your threshold. You could Debug the distance value to see how much the difference really is.

Comment: Could we see the rest of the movement script, particularly the `Update`/`FixedUpdate` methods for more context?

Comment: Could you show us the rest of your code? In particular how exactly you love the object?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I managed to solve the problem by switching the statements in _if_ function. I posted the update as an answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I managed to solve the mouse flickering problem by making the public variable *radius* and later make the *if* statement to check if the radius is smaller than the position of the mouse pointer.

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position)) <= radius)
    {

        return;
    }

    transform.Translate(0f, move, 0f);
    transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, rotation);

    
}
```

Insted of `Vector2.Distance(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), transform.position) <= 0.1f)`

Also, I made a beginner mistake by continuously trying to place the *if* statement in *Update()* function instead of placing it in *LateUpdate()* where is player movement logic.